# Render link description in navigation block

Tags: menus, navigation, links, description

I use [Navigation block](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/navigation-block/) (Navigation menu) for my header menu.

The problem I faced is that I can't render on front link description for the menu items that has children.

I tried `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter to customize this somehow, using this code and it didn't help.

```
function prefix_nav_description( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    if ( !empty( $item->description ) ) {
        $item_output = str_replace( $args->link_after . '</a>', '<span class="menu-item-description">' . $item->description . '</span>' . $args->link_after . '</a>', $item_output );
    }
 
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'prefix_nav_description', 10, 4 );
```

So my question is: **what should be done to render link description for items with children in navigation block**.

*Thank you in advance!*

**Added 2023-10-28**

As I understand this is because there are different files for rendering menu and submenu items:

link
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/blocks/navigation-link.php

submenu

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/blocks/navigation-submenu.php

And for navigation-submenu there is no logic for rendering link description.

But question is the same: **how to enabling link description for submenu**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by using [WordPress Filter hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)

I use the filter `render_block`, to hook in altering the existing HTML

So I created `custom_render_block_core_navigation_submenu` hook function.

Inside my hook I am using conditions to avoid storing my modified code in the database.

- Target the type of block (core/navigation-submenu)
- Only render in the front-end
- Don’t alter the HTML in wp-json

In the function I check is title or description is avaliable, if yes, I create new list item element with title and/or description and insert this list item inside child list right after the opening

```
function custom_render_block_core_navigation_submenu(string $block_content, array $block): string
{
    if (
        isset($block['blockName']) &&
        'core/navigation-submenu' === $block['blockName'] &&
        !is_admin() &&
        !wp_is_json_request()
    ) {
        $additional_html = '';

        // Add description if available.
        if (!empty($block['attrs']['title']) || !empty($block['attrs']['description'])) {
            $additional_html .= '<li class="wp-block-navigation-item">';

            // Add title if available.
            if (!empty($block['attrs']['title'])) {
                $additional_html .= '<span class="wp-block-navigation-item__label">';
                $additional_html .= wp_kses_post($block['attrs']['title']);
                $additional_html .= '</span>';
            }

            // Add description if available.
            if (!empty($block['attrs']['description'])) {
                $additional_html .= '<span class="wp-block-navigation-item__description">';
                $additional_html .= wp_kses_post($block['attrs']['description']);
                $additional_html .= '</span>';
            }

            $additional_html .= '</li>';
        }

        // Find the position to insert $additional_html
        $position = strpos($block_content, '<ul class="wp-block-navigation__submenu-container wp-block-navigation-submenu">');
        if ($position !== false) {
            // Insert $additional_html right after the opening <ul> tag
            $position += strlen('<ul class="wp-block-navigation__submenu-container wp-block-navigation-submenu">');
            $block_content = substr_replace($block_content, $additional_html, $position, 0);
        }
    }

    return $block_content;
}

add_filter('render_block', 'custom_render_block_core_navigation_submenu', null, 2);
```